# View helper in EJS / JMVC / canJs

Tags: ejs, canjs, canjs-view

Planning to use view helpers in my JMVC application. Tried to implement select_tag helper function in my ejs file but failed to obtain required results. 
Below is the code

In Controller :

```
this.choice= [{value: 1,    text: 'First Choice'}, 
              {value: 2,    text: 'Second Choice'} ];                
this.element.html(initView({choice:this.choice}));
```

In Ejs file :

```
<%= select_tag('elementId', 1,  this.choice) %>
```

Reference
https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/ViewHelpers

Do we need to steal any packages ? is there any sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to the helpers I did three things...

1. I updated the first line of file jquerypp/view/helpers/helpers.js from:

   ```
   steal('jquerypp/view/ejs').then(function($){
   ```

   to

   ```
   steal('jquerypp/view/ejs').then(function(){
   ```
2. I stole 'jquerypp/view/helpers' in the controller.
3. Finally, in the ejs instead of

   ```
   <%= select_tag('elementId', 1,  this.choice) %>
   ```

   I used

   ```
   <%== select_tag('elementId', 1,  this.choice) %>
   ```

to force ejs to render the select block as part of the page instead of rendering an escaped quoted version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have to include this file: https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/source/browse/trunk/src/view.js

There are all helpers. So steal it :)